# CSS Flex: Text escapes from container

Tags: html, css, layout, text, flexbox

Having an issue with CSS flex layout that I can't figure out.

HTML:

```
<div class="image-view">
    <div class="info">
        <span class="label title">d37ci4x.jpg</span>
        <span class="label scale">100%</span>
    </div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/rfcsACA.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-view {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}

.image-view .info {
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
}

.image-view .info .title {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex: 5 1 100%;
}

.image-view .info .scale {
    flex: 1 0 1em;
    padding-left: 2em;
    border-left: 1px #000 solid;
}
```

Result:

[image: screenshot of issue]

Also live at http://jsfiddle.net/omhaohyd/

The issue here is that the "100%" text is somehow being pushed to the right, out of its container. Removing the padding hasn't helped - it correctly shrinks the container and moves the text up against the left edge, but the container ends up *too* small, so the text still flows out of it. Giving the `.scale` more space (increasing the `1em` and reducing the `.title`'s `100%`) does fix it, but adds a lot of whitespace around the "100%" as well, and I simply don't want it that large.

This is in Firefox 30.0 on Lubuntu x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because for the `.scale` element, you are using the following flex property: `flex: 1 0 1em;`, which restricts its calculated width to 1em maximum. Combined with the 2em left padding you are assigning it to the text, this causes the text to be pushed out of the container.

Possible fix will be to remove the `flex-basis` property and set it to auto, i.e. `flex: 1 0 auto`: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/omhaohyd/2/

Comment: Interesting. I'm not 100% on what `flex-basis` does. Your solution fixes the escaping text but also makes the field larger than necessary; however I played with it a bit and got it working how I wanted: `flex: 1 0 3em` - am I correct in understanding that this means "use a base size of 3em, but grow to as much as 1x that, and shrink to as much as 0x that, as necessary"?

Comment: @Rena That is correct. Flex-basis can be a fixed, unit value (i.e. "I want you to be only this big") or a unitless value (i.e. "I want you to have this ratio relative to other containers on the same cross axis"). However, do note that by assigning a `3em` value you will limit its width to 3em, and text will overflow if they fill the width :)

Answer (score 0):

This will display close to what you are wanting.

```
.image-view .info .scale {
    flex: 1 0 3em;
    padding-left: .5em;
    border-left: 1px #000 solid;
}
```